# How to add Children to a Xaml.Document like Underline

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

If I would like to create a Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents object and add children to it, and do this programatically, how would one go about doing this?

I assumed it would look something like this:

```
var run = new Run();
run.Text = "Foo";

var und = new Underline();
und.ElementStart.Parent = run; // <= Does not compile...
```

I would like to end up with the equivalent to this Xaml markup:

```
 <Underline x:Name="myName">
            <Run Text="As per this MSDN Article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198241.aspx" />
  </Underline>
```

Except I would like to build this structure programatically. There must be a way, as every xaml mark up has an underlying CLR Object associated with it. AT least that is my understanding.

I should mention this is a Windows RT (Metro) Win8 application (not WPF or SilverLight) written in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,replace

```
und.ElementStart.Parent = run;
```

with

```
und.Inlines.Add(run);
```